# Pearson Correlation from multiple rows

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to calculate the Pearson Correlation between two arrays.

The function CORR only accepts 2 values which has to be in a table. In my procedure I select multiple rows of numbers from two different sets and I want to calculate the correlation from them.

EDIT:

The corr function is an oracle function which calculates the pearson correlation between two values. Here is the problem. I want to calculate the correlation between two arrays which says to me array1 is similar to array2 of for example 50%.

Comment: Can you clarify a little.  Is the `CORR` call part of the procedure, or the results of the procedure are going into the `CORR` call?

Comment: What problems are you having implementing the formula?

Comment: have edited my question

Comment: You need to provide some more information.  Show your code and any error messages you may be seeing.

Comment: There is no error message and why code? This is an normal function which you can use in sql or plsql and my question is how can i use the function to calculate an correlation over 2 arrays not over 2 numbers. Can i handle it with plsql and if how

Comment: Why code?  To demonstrate you've tried something.  This is not a "do my homework for me" or "do my job for me" site.  Show us you've made an effort and most likely someone will offer some help.

Comment: In future i'll do my best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply calculate average of pairwise correlations

```
select 
  (abs(corr1) + abs(corr2) + abs(corr3))/3 as Avg_Corr
from (
  SELECT 
    CORR(a.col1, b.col1) as corr1,
    CORR(a.col2, b.col2) as corr2,
    CORR(a.col3, b.col3) as corr3
  FROM table1 a, table2 b
  WHERE a.id = b.id
)
```

or use more complex but more adequate [generalization of Pearson correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RV_coefficient) (there are no internal function in Oracle for this)